# How to find amplitude and frequency of an incoming sinusoidal signal (analog) in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In my application, there's an incoming sinusoidal signal and I need to find its frequency and amplitude by VHDL coding. This is non-synthesisable as we are not implementing it on FPGA.

So far I've been using the "MAXIMUM" function of VHDL to find the amplitude. In testbench, I am  successfully generating the sine wave, and so in my source code I am using the maximum function. But the problem is that I am not getting one value but several.

Here's the sample of my code;

```
--in the entity 
(input_sine : real;
    Amp_out : real;
    frq_out : real);
end entity;

--in the architecture,

signal S_amp : real := 0.0;

process

begin 

  Amp_out <= MAXIMUM(input_sine, S_amp);

  wait for 1 us;

end process;
```

I expect the output to be just one value i.e, the maximum amplitude value of the input sinusoidal wave. And also to find its frequency. I'm not sure how to proceed, neither am I with this maximum function. So, someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The input is a `real` i.e. a single floating point value. a single value cannot represent a whole sinusoid wave. You will need to evaluate at least the number of samples of the sinusoid in a whole period of the sinusoid. And I'm assuming here that it's a single sinusoid. Stacked sinusoids will require something like an FFT.

Comment: By the way, it this a homework assignment? Starting to code before you know how to determine a signal's frequency and amplitude seems the wrong approach. ESPECIALLY is you want to code in VHDL, which is not aimed at general programming. You should first read up in signal processing theory and Fourier calculus

Answer (score 4):

The VHDL `MAXIMUM` function returns the maximum (ie larger) value of its two inputs. Your two inputs are `input_sine` and `S_amp`, which is always 0.0. So, `Amp_out` will equal `input_sine` when `input_sine` is positive and 0.0 when it is negative.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4nsb

To find the maximum value of `input_sine` (ie its amplitude) and its frequency, you're going to have to write some code. This is a hardware description language, not Matlab.

Comment: Hello Mr Taylor, thanks for replying so quick! If possible, could you please tell me the logic or the method in implementing this functionality?

Comment: I can't really. Finding the maximum is going to be easier than finding the frequency. To find the maximum you could keep track of the maximum value found and if the latest value is bigger, it becomes the new maximum value. But I don't know your requirements - is -1.1 bigger than +1.0? (Or not?) Is the mean 0,0? (Or not?)

Comment: @Sumukh we're here to help you find issues in your code. You cannot expect us to design your algorithm or write your code. That's your own job.